# Windows Default Alarm System bug, set for 8am runs at 8am and 8pm

Tags: windows-10

My windows alarm was set for 8am everyday, I use my windows alarm to wake myself up in the morning, for the past week, and I don't know how long before that, because I wasn't counting runs at 8PM, just today I closed the 8PM alarm and it opened again and ran.

Just so you know when the 8PM alarm comes on it says "Alarm 8AM ~ Wake UP" it runs at the wrong time and display's the wrong thing, I was thinking if this ways a date time bug, but I am in the correct time zone with the correct date. The '8:00 AM' alarm is only set once for 8am.

I've checked other questions in the same area, and none of them are quite as special as this one.

Comment: This is a bug in the software itself, and there's nothing within your immediate powers to fix it, save by notifying Windows of the problem.